# How can I make sure that man has pages installed?

Tags: arch-linux, man, man-db

Everytime I run `man` it returns an error as if no man page entries were installed.  Here's an example:

`% man man`

> No manual entry for man

However, I have installed the packages `man-db` and `man-pages`, yet it doesn't return a single entry.  I have tried with many commands like `man ls`, and others.

Also, if i run `whatis man`, the following is returned:

> man: nothing appropriate.

Comment: `man --debug man` may output some useful information.

Comment: `man -u man` should try to rebuild the cache.

Comment: I tried both, still it says `no manual entry for man`.

Comment: @fra-san, the output shows the configuration at /etc/man_db.conf.

Comment: `strace man man` and see what it tries to access and do, and what it dies on. Mine logs 884 actions.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it looks like it's looking up many directories and trying to open them.  Finally it returns this: `+++ exited with 16 +++`.  Many calls at readlink returns this error: `Invalid argument`.

Comment: @Procer.Scvtvlatvs If you feel you are not seeing anything useful in `--debug`'s output you may want to share it here as a pastebin, so that others may help you dig into your issue.

Comment: @fra-san Thanks for the suggestion.  The following paste is that of [man --debug man](https://pastebin.com/maZ1HaiS)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The following paste is that of [strace man man](https://pastebin.com/tAfr3VrV).

Comment: @Procer.Scvtvlatvs On a regular Arch, the fundamental man pages are installed in `/usr/share/man`. As expected, your `man` config lists that one among the directories to search, but then it doesn't add it to the search path, as if it wasn't readable. Oddly, `strace` shows that `man` doesn't even try to access it. I can't come up with any plausible explanation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you install the packages `man-db` and `man-pages` you need to run the `mandb` command to generate the search database for manpage entries.

EDIT (thanks to @fra-san): If you set the `MANPATH` environment variable, you also need to unset it. If that variable is set, `man` ignores the paths specified in the config file `man_db.conf`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it.  I also had to `unset MANPATH` so that `mandb` could use the `man_db.conf` settings.

Comment: Adding the line `unset MANPATH` in my `.zshrc`, then `source ~/.zshrc` solved it for me too. Thank you!